# Why Can't I Connect to My Database Over the Internet

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an sql database called roottesting and I manage it at the ip 192.168.1.121. I also have a simple java application that connects to it (or rather, is supposed to connect to it) over the Internet with a user named 'user' that has a host of '%', which I know will make it usable for any computer that uses it. Here is the method in which my program connects to the database:

```
public void addTestEntry(TestEntry testEntry)
        throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

    tests.add(testEntry);

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

    String url = "jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.121/roottesting";

    con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "user", "S@cajaw3a");

    PreparedStatement statement = con
            .prepareStatement("insert into tests values(?, ?, ?)");

    statement.setString(1, testEntry.getName());
    statement.setInt(2, testEntry.getCorrect());
    statement.setInt(3, testEntry.getIncorrect());

    statement.executeUpdate();

    con.close();
}
```

This will work every time I download the program on another computer on my home network, Beigecedar, but when I try to do it on another network, like my school's network, it does not work and gives that standard message that signals that the database could not be found. Can anyone give me a suggestion about how to connect to my database over the Internet, no matter what network the computer running the program is in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IP Address you are connecting to is what is called a [Reserved IP Address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reserved_IP_addresses)

It is local to your network only ( 192.168.0.0/16 ). With that aside let's address 2 things.

If you are allowed to connect to your own computer from the internet (IE: Firewall and ports open) then you can connect using your [public IP Address](https://www.google.com/#q=what+is+my+ip)

You also have to consider what ports your school allow to be open. They may very well block the ports required for you to make this connection.

Comment: Lol nah, you must have ipv6 enabled like me, check this one instead -> http://ip-lookup.net/

Comment: If when you try to connect and still have problems we can start a chat and I can try to walk you through it bro

Comment: Take your time, I'll be on for a while. Trying to get to 2k rep before weekends over

Comment: Delete that comment ^^ -- Dont list your public IP, last thing you want is to be Dossed, or worse, you are running a database and someone to drop all your tables

Comment: Try and join this room -> http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/91224/room-for-james-mcgivern-and-jesse

Comment: Ah, you need at least 20 rep. Go earn that stuffs man. Things to check now since you know what to do is what port you are connecting to for the database. If mysql default is port 3306, need to get that bad boy opened on the computer that has the database on it for inbound connections. Outbound on your ma's computer is probably already set to do whatever, Now you just need to google this. At this point it kind of advances past the scope of this question

Comment: I am connecting with port 3306, the my.ini file on my xampp software confirms this. The only problem is that my mom's computer can't open firewall for some reason, probably a virus or something, it's old! Anyways, do you think that that would bring a communications link failure error? If so, then I think that could be my problem.

Answer (score 0):

192.168.1.121 is a local IP, you need a Public IP. If you have internet you can use something like www.whatismyip.com to know your public ip. The problem with that IP is may change with the time so your app also may broke in the future.

Or use a firewall to reruote public IP to your pc in case you are behind a router

Comment: Should I use this ip, my public one, which is 2601:602:c280:73:c846:6476:23cf:ab11 according to the website www.whatismyip.com, in the form of jdbc:mysql://my_ip/roottesting?

Comment: is weird your ip should be something like `200.8.46.219`

Comment: Anyway that addres only work if you direct connect to your cable/modem. If you connect your modem to a router you will need PORT FORWARDING so your route send the db request to your PC.

Comment: When I got to website, it said my ip was 2601:602:c280:73:c846:6476:23cf:ab11

Answer (score 0):

192.x.x.x is a private address range.  It will only be available locally, and not beyond the internet router.  Look at setting up NAT (network address translation) if you wish to access this host from other sites.